# Whisper shh_getMessages not receiving posted messages with shh_post

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

I am using Whisper `shh_post` and posting some messages (multicast with no "to") and that seems to be working. I.e.: the response's error count is zero.

And then I have another small console app that I run the `shh_getMessages` method to get that message I just posted, but that returns no messages, and no errors also.

I don't have any filters in the receiving side and the only parameter I have there is the count: "0x7"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Today I've got a simillar issue with not receiving messages, but in Java. I could solve the problem with setting up another node on another pc.

I don't know exactly why but sending and receiving messages on the same Computer (with two diffrent nodes running) didn't work out. So maybe the problem is that the nodes are not sending/listening on the right I/O ports.

So my suggestion for you:

1. Make a [private network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#operating-a-private-network) with two nodes and two computers.
2. Send a message from your first node (be sure that the payload is Ascii, otherwise you receive 0x0). Optional: Set a topic or the parameter to.
3. Check the logs of your nodes (sender/receiver) to see if a message was sent and if the node received a broadcast: Should look similar to this logs:

   ```
   I0320 16:47:54.407804 whisper/whisperv2/peer.go:173] Peer 37254dbccd1efc04 127.0.0.1:30305 broadcasted 1 
   message(s) I0320 16:47:54.708006   whisper/whisperv2/peer.go:173] Peer 37254dbccd1efc04
       127.0.0.1:30305 broadcasted 0 message(s)
   ```
4. If you have nothing in the logs then maybe your node hasn't started whisper. You can start it with --shh and --rpcapi shh
5. Look if you received something -> If not, set a topic-filter or to-filter and try it again.